# Matrix of confusion - percentage per row or column?

Tags: binary-data, percentage, confusion-matrix

When you build a prediction model on a binary variable, you have a confusion matrix which compares your predictions according to real values.

```
|         | pred 0  | pred 1 |
| ------- | ------- | ------ |
| real 0  |   250   |    5   |
| real 1  |    10   |   45   |
```

From this table, you can calculate the precision of your model. My question is not about this, but **when you want to calculate percentage** in this table. You can:

- consider rows: percentage of real value well predict (and so you have to divide each value by the sum per row).
- consider columns: percentage of correct prediction (divide by the sum per column).

Depending of the values, the results are quite different.
In general, is there a way we have to consider more than the other ?

```
 # sum per row                      # sum per column
|         | pred 0  | pred 1 |     |         | pred 0  | pred 1 |
| ------- | ------- | ------ |     | ------- | ------- | ------ |
| real 0  |   98%   |   2%   |     | real 0  |   96%   |  10%   |
| real 1  |   18%   |  82%   |     | real 1  |    4%   |  90%   |
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Percentage of what? Either can be justified - and a third way is to have all 4 numbers sum to 100%. All depict different things, and what you choose depends on what you are trying to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule and this is why such tables have a whole bunch of statistics associated with them:

- Sensitivity
- Specificity
- Positive predictive value
- Negative predictive value
- Prevalence

are perhaps the most common but see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values) for many more. Virtually every percentage that you can calculate (and many combinations) has some utility for some situations.

You have to think about the particular situation and which things would be very good, very bad or neutral. Even within a field, it could vary. For instance, suppose this is from results for a diagnostic test in medicine. Then which is important would depend on:

- The seriousness of the disease
- The efficacy of treatment
- The side effects of treatment
- The harms of false positive (e.g. cost, additional procedures, psychological stress, lost work) and false negatives (e.g. disease progression).